# ORA-00936: missing expression in order by case

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Hello i have problem with missing expression in this code:

```
create or replace view tabulkaliga as 
  select t.nazov, zs.zapasov, zs.vyhier*nvl(tr.bodyvyhra,0)+zs.remiz*nvl(tr.bodyremiza,0) body, zs.vyhier,zs.remiz,zs.prehier,sl.dali,sl.dostali from
      tim t join 
      ligatim lt on t.id=lt.tim join 
      liga l on lt.liga=l.id join 
      sport s on l.sport=s.id join 
      trvanie tr on s.trvanie=tr.id inner join 
      zapasstat zs on zs.liga=l.id and t.id=zs.tim inner join 
      skoreliga sl on sl.liga=l.id and sl.tim=t.id 
        order by 
          case 
            when tr.bodyvyhra is null then (zs.vyhier+0.5*zs.remiz)/ZS.ZAPASOV desc,ZS.VYHIER desc
            else body desc, zs.vyhier desc, sl.dali desc
          end;
```

please help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `desc` and `asc` keywords are not allowed in the `case`.  Plus, only one column at a time is allowed.  You can try this:

```
order by (case when tr.bodyvyhra is null then (zs.vyhier+0.5*zs.remiz)/ZS.ZAPASOV else body end) desc,
         ZS.VYHIER desc,
         sl.dali desc
```

Note that this assumes that `body` is of a numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
order by 
      case 
        when tr.bodyvyhra is null then (zs.vyhier+0.5*zs.remiz)/ZS.ZAPASOV desc,ZS.VYHIER desc
        else body desc, zs.vyhier desc, sl.dali desc
      end;
```

with

```
order by 
      case when tr.bodyvyhra is null then (zs.vyhier+0.5*zs.remiz)/ZS.ZAPASOV end desc,
      case when tr.bodyvyhra is not null then body end desc,
      ZS.VYHIER end desc,
      case when tr.bodyvyhra is not null then sl.dali end desc;
```

I split your order by in several cases because:
1) case can contain only expressions (or conditons)
2) expressions must be in one "type group"